# jQuery: How retain the value of the attribute on an element after dropping using sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable table row with a `data-order` attribute in each `td` order by 1 to 4. I want to retain it's value on the same order even after sorting. example: If `<td data-order="2">` is going to be drop on the last, then it's new value of it's attribute will be 4.

```js
$("tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
```

```css
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="1">test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="2">test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="3">test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="4">test4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event **[update()](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)** of sortable plugin. This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

```
 $( "tbody" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "tbody td" ).each(function(i){
         $(this).data("order",i+1);
         $(this).attr("data-order",i+1);
       })
    }
 }).disableSelection();
```

### Working Demo

Comment: As a side note, this won't update attribute. Now it is really depending if OP really need to update the attribute or the data object. To update the attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/fjfmfaqk/

Comment: `sure` OP can use `  $(this).attr("order",i+1);` for that.

Comment: No, it must be `$(this).attr("data-order",i+1);`